# On the turn after Haste ends, can you use a reaction?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, actions, reactions

The description of the Haste spell concludes with:

> When the spell ends, the target can't move or take actions until after its next turn, as a wave of lethargy sweeps over it.

Could the target still use a reaction (to, say, throw up a Shield spell if needed) or is a reaction considered a type of action?

Since the spell depends on concentration, it could end unexpectedly if the caster loses concentration on it, leaving the target in a perilous situation.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Yes, you can

Jeremy Crawford confirms this on [Twitter](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/03/28/after-haste-ends-phb-says-target-cant-move-or-take-actions-does-this-include-reactions/).

> **Clint McReynolds**
>   *[@CJMcReynolds](https://twitter.com/CJMcReynolds)*
>
> @JeremyECrawford After Haste ends, PHB says target can't move or take actions. Does this include reactions? Advantage to hit target?
>
> ---
>
> **Jeremy Crawford**
>   *[@JeremyECrawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford)*
>
> Actions and reactions are different. If an effect, like the haste spell, shuts off one, it doesn't necessarily shut off the other. [#DnD](https://twitter.com/hashtag/DnD?src=hash)

## Other supporting evidence

In the PHB, the Incapacitated condition differentiates between actions and reactions:

> **Incapacitated**, PHB 290
>
> An incapacitated creature can't take actions or reactions.

## Ramifications

Actions and reactions are different.

If you had *haste* and *fly* on (concentration can be dealt with via potion, buff from ally, magic item, etc), and someone cast a *dispel magic* on you, you can still catch yourself with a *feather fall*.

If you were frozen with lethargy, you can still muster the "energy" to cast *shield*, *hellish rebuke*, *absorb elements*, or even *counterspell*, and perhaps you can narrate it as one desperate wave of the hand and a breathless incantation.

Ending *haste* does not incapacitate you. It just makes you lethargic and unable to take actions.

Comment: I wish the PHB were a little more precise -- it defines a reaction as a special kind of action, but Crawford's tweet suggests that that is not really what the developers intended. :-/

Comment: You can further support this answer by quoting the section of the PHB (page189) which states: "anything that deprives you of your ability to take actions
also prevents you from taking a bonus action.", there is no analogous section for reactions.

Answer (score 15):

No.

A reaction is defined as "a special kind of action" in the rules (PHB, p. 190), and therefore is governed by anything affecting actions. It's special-ness is not defined as to be immune to action-depriving situations.

Furthermore, it would be odd for your extreme lethargy to prevent you from intentionally taking actions, but let up in a flash when you want to take a reaction, and then return.

I understand that Jeremy Crawford rules differently, but his Twitter rulings are no longer official and this has not been addressed officially.

Comment: I don't think the lethargy 'let[s] up in a flash . . . and then return[s]."  Instead, I think the character reflexively reacts with a surge of adrenaline in an "expletive moment."