# Can you use a readied action after Haste?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, readied-action

Let's say before I even enter combat, I cast Blade Ward as a ready action, and saying "I'll release this as soon as Haste ends," then cast Haste on myself

After Haste ends, it says that

> When the spell ends, the target can't move or take actions until the end of its next turn.

Apparently, you can still take reactions even after Haste, is it the same for a readied action?

An example for a sequence of events in case my description is confusing:

Let's say my party enters a potentially dangerous area, so before that, I'll cast/prepare Blade Ward as a ready action, stating that I'll release it for after Haste ends (but I don't cast Haste yet).

Once we enter a place with enemies (and we're not ambushed), I cast Haste on myself. Let's say after some turns of combat and my turn is over, Haste ends, and I'm left not able to do anything next turn as per Haste's effects. During that turn (when I'm not able to do anything), Haste has ended so Blade Ward should be released/take effect (if it's possible)

Comment: Let's say my party enters a potentially dangerous area, so before that, I'll cast/prepare Blade Ward as a ready action, stating that I'll prepare it for after Haste ends. Once we enter a place with enemies (and we're not ambushed), I cast Haste on myself.

Let's say after my turn is over, Haste ends, and I'm left not able to do anything next turn since as per Haste's effects. During that turn, I'm planning to release Blade Ward in case anything attacks me. Is that possible?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## It does not work, but not for the reason you think

### Two concentrations

Readying a spell needs concentration, so your readied Blade Ward end the moment you start casting Haste (which also needs concentration).

> As soon as you start casting a spell or using a special ability that requires concentration, your concentration on another effect ends instantly.

### Ready lasts only until your next turn

Player's Handbook Errata:

> Ready (p. 193). You have **until the start of your next turn** to use a readied action.

## How it could work

If *someone else* cast Haste on you, you can cast Blade Ward from your normal action<sup>1</sup> in the round before you expect Haste to end.

---

1) not the one gained from Haste

Comment: One more reason: a reaction is "a special action", so Haste also prevents you from using reactions when it ends.

Comment: @miniman reactions are actually separate. Bonus actions are special actions but reactions hold their own place. The incapacitated condition specifically mentions that your can't use actions *or* reactions

Comment: @DavidCoffron Hmmm, interesting. Bonus actions and reactions are both "special actions", but bonus actions explicitly state that anything that prevents you from using an action also prevents bonus actions, while reactions don't. I was going to ask a question, but [it was already in the related questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59079/15469) :)

Comment: I'm not certain of the first point here. "A concentration spell ends the instant you start casting another concentration spell" (https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/951889482298540032) and I don't believe that readying a spell is equivalent to starting to cast it.

Comment: @Elia: It is equivalent to starting to cast it (or actually casting it, technically), specifically because readying a spell means you cast the spell immediately but hold its energy to release later. That said, the first point is actually the other way around from what you suggest: the already readied Blade Ward spell requires concentration to keep it readied - and Haste is not being readied, just cast normally, but it requires concentration as well.

Comment: I don't recall the precise wording, but I think that readying a spell doesn't count as casting it except for the purpose of the spell slot. I'm too far from my books to check at the moment, though.

Comment: @Elia: The precise wording of [Ready](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Ready) says: "When you ready a spell, you cast it as normal but hold its energy, which you release with your reaction when the trigger occurs." It counts as casting a spell for everything *except* the actual effects of the spell occurring.

Comment: How did such a niche question with a simple answer get this much attention?

Answer (score 2):

### This will not work

Your plan to ready Blade Ward ahead of time before entering combat is unfortunately not possible. As you can see in this related answer, [you have only one round to release the readied Blade Ward](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/64496/33707)

Answer (score 2):

### This won't work

Even if you have haste cast on you by someone else, "as soon as haste ends" is not a valid trigger since it is not a perceivable condition.

> First, you decide what **perceivable circumstance** will trigger your reaction.

Your DM, however, might rule that the character feels the slow-motion wears off as perceivable condition, thus allowing you to ready an action (release the Blade Ward).

Comment: I would argue that being unable to move or take actions is perceivable. Maybe the actual magic ending couldn't be specifically perceived unless you have Detect Magic running, but finding yourself unable to take actions or move would be pretty noticeable if you ask me.

However, no it won't work anyway, as elaborated by the accepted answers above