# When the Haste spell ends on a creature, do attackers have advantage against that creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, advantage-and-disadvantage

The rules for the [*haste*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/haste) spell state the following:

> When the spell ends, the target can’t move or take actions until after its next turn, as a wave of lethargy sweeps over it.
>
> --- *Player's Handbook* p. 250

Does this give attackers an advantage against you as you cannot move? What about making Strength/Dexterity saves during this period? I find it unclear as to what it means by 'can’t move or take actions'?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It means exactly what it says: No movement (speed becomes 0), and no actions (action, bonus action or reaction*).

The rest of the mechanics apply normally: no disadvantage, saves as needed. It doesn't say that any specific condition applies, so nothing else matters...

*(As was noted in the comments and in the related question [On the turn after Haste ends, can you use a reaction?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59079/on-the-turn-after-haste-ends-can-you-use-a-reaction) , reaction should probably not be included.
However, my interpretation goes along the "reaction is a special kind of action" PHB quote)

Comment: According to [On the turn after Haste ends, can you use a reaction?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59079/on-the-turn-after-haste-ends-can-you-use-a-reaction), you can still use reactions.

Comment: @RobWatts According to that link it seems that reactions are "a special kind of action".

Comment: @Vadruk: That is according to the answer with fewer upvotes. While reactions may be a "special kind of action", there's no rule that says things that prevent actions also prevent reactions (and, in fact, everything that prevents reactions specifically says so, separately from actions). They are "special", after all.

Comment: @V2Blast After reading both answers a couple more time, I have to agree with you.